# Android bluetooth - Discoverable and many open connections at the same time?

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

A few months ago I have coded a messenger program in C# which enables many clients to connect to a server and have a chat.

Now, I want to code the same program for android. After reading the bluetooth article in Android Developers, it seems that this is possible for a device to hold many bluetooth sockets at the same time + be discoverable (I'm talking about the server). The only action the said that should not work togather with bluetooth sockets is discovery, but since the client runs that, it doesn't change much.

But what made me unsure if it's possible to be done, is the fact that there is NO such an application in the android market! (Atleast not after a quick check.) There are many bluetooth chat apps, but none of them allows multi clients.

So before I begin coding that, I want to make sure it is possible, and make sure that holding, say, 5 tcp sockets won't kill the server phone.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hey, did you find out the answer to this please?

Comment: I did search in many sources, but I haven't come to one clear answer (As far as I remember... It was a while ago). From the majority of the sources, it appears that it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link I found:
["Multi-device extension of the official Android Bluetooth Chat example"](https://github.com/polyclef/BluetoothChatMulti)

Is that what you wanted?